# How do I access COM-Port with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, arduino, arduino-uno

Here the serial communication port shows error it cannot be accessed .....But the serial communication port works perfect in arduino, so it cant be the port problem, its not the driver problem either, the driver is updated and works well, so the problem can be in the code .....i am a newbie to C#.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort myport;
    private string in_data;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 19200;
        myport.PortName = pn.Text;
        myport.Parity = Parity.None;
        myport.DataBits = 8;
        myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myport.DataReceived += myport_DataReceived;
        try
        {
            myport.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!!");
        }

    }

    void myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        *in_data = myport.ReadLine();***
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));

    }
    private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] newData = in_data.Split(',');

        bv.Text = newData[0];
        bi.Text = newData[1];
        pv.Text = newData[2];
        pi.Text = newData[3];
        t.Text = newData[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: Have you tried running your exe As Administrator?

Comment: Yes, sir have tried running .exe file as admin ....... but no data gets displayed in the text box ......

Comment: I could not find out what is wrong with the code. Data is not getting displayed in the text box.......

Comment: 1. Check if another application is using it while you are trying to access it.
2. Check COM settings if they are right.

Comment: This is the error i get :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Comment: Are you sure the configuration is right? Both sides need to agree on baud rate, parity etc. Is the Arduino actually sending data terminated with `\r\n`? Is it sending EOF? Also, don't `DataReceived` like this - either use `ReadExisting`, or use a separate thread that simply calls `ReadLine` in a loop. What's in `e` when you get into the `DataReceived` handler?

Comment: The baud rate, parity, end bit etc all are synchronized.....there aint any problem with them .......

Comment: No other program is accessing the com port .......except the Visual Studio

Comment: To be honest, i have no idea what the e is ......i was just copying from an youtube tutorial .....because i am an electronics guys .....with basic knowledge in C & C++ ......have no idea about C# ......
And thanks a tone Luaan ........i really loved the way you explored every possibilities .......
I ll try to use the ReadLine in a loop ....that sounds better than this  ....

Comment: Instead of `ReadLine` use the `ReadExisting` function; append the received string to a global string and process everything until the new line character... Or if you prefer the loop version in another thread (that's what I prefer too), use the same algorithm (i.e. append to a buffer and then extract). That's because sometimes the same serial communication is notified in two pieces to the program..

Answer (score 0):

> it cannot be accessed

This may indicates that the port doesnt exists or is already in use.
Maybe another application is already listening on this port. (arduino?)

`Comport.Open()` Exceptions are descibed here:
[MSDN SerialPort.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open(v=vs.110).aspx)